# Can't get correct height hover effect with jQuery and CSS Transitions

Tags: jquery, css

When I hover over one of my cards, I want the bottom section to smoothly move upwards. With the bottom section of the hovered card noticeably higher than the other non-hovered cards - see screenshot below. I also want the restaurant name to move up, which I am achieving.

Another problem is that my code is currently producing a shaky effect on hover which I don't want. This could be due to some incorrect way I am using jQuery with the CSS transition.

My latest attempt (of many) including can be found in my: [JS FIDDLE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/wf1g0n0k/3/)

HTML:

```
<a href="http://placeholder-url.com" class="previously-viewed__item">

    <img class="previously-viewed__image" src="http://img.static-bookatable.com/hawksmoor-guildhall-barbican-moorgate-london-1.jpg?id=d1d0f725e6517d92e341f4639ce23a44.jpg&width=320&height=201&scale=both&mode=crop&quality=90.jpg">

    <div class="previously-viewed__content">

      <h3 class="previously-viewed__name">Hawksmoor Guildhall</h3>

      <h3 class="previously-viewed__location">City of London</h3>

    </div>

  </a>

<a href="http://placeholder-url.com" class="previously-viewed__item">

    <img class="previously-viewed__image" src="http://img.static-bookatable.com/the-bull-and-gate-kentish-town-london-1.jpg?id=bcdf856498e6538f7784cd438cd15c94.jpg&width=320&height=201&scale=both&mode=crop&quality=90">

    <div class="previously-viewed__content">

      <h3 class="previously-viewed__name">The Bull and Gate</h3>

      <h3 class="previously-viewed__location">Kentish Town</h3>

    </div>

  </a>
```

CSS:

```
.previously-viewed__item {
      float: left;
      width: 31%;
      background: #fff;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
      margin-right: 1%;
      transition: box-shadow 0.5s;
      transition-property: box-shadow;
      transition-duration: 0.5s;
      transition-timing-function: initial;
      transition-delay: initial;
      margin-bottom: 80px;
      padding-bottom: 30px;
      border-bottom: solid 2px #ccd3da;
      text-decoration: none  
  }

  .previously-viewed__image {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 320px;
    padding-bottom: 26px;
    transition: margin-bottom 0.5s;
  }

  .previously-viewed__content {
    width: 100%;
    height: 136px;
    transition: height 0.5s;
  }

  .previously-viewed__name {
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    font-family: 'HelveticaNeue-Medium', 'Helvetica Neue Medium', Helvetica, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #2C393E;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 24px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top: -5px;
    height: 5px
  }

  .previously-viewed__location {
    padding-left: 20px;
    color: #1c1c1c;
    font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;
    line-height: 24px;
    font-weight: 500;
    margin-top: 10px;
    font-size: 1rem;
    padding-bottom: 46px;
  }
```

JS / JQUERY:

```
 $('.previously-viewed__item').mouseenter(function() {

        $($(this).find('.previously-viewed__content')).css({'height':'166px'});
        $($(this).find('.previously-viewed__image')).css({'margin-bottom':'6px'});    

        $(this).css({'box-shadow': '0 0px 7px 0 #85959B, 0 0px 7px 0 #85959B'});

      });

      $('.previously-viewed__item').mouseleave(function() {

        $($(this).find('.previously-viewed__content')).css({'height':'136px'});
        $($(this).find('.previously-viewed__image')).css({'margin-bottom':'36px'});                 
        $(this).css({'box-shadow': 'none'});

       });
```

Effect on hover I am trying to achieve:

[image]

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/wf1g0n0k/6/

Comment: thanks @JOPLOmacedo this looks good, but can you provide some explanation so I can accept your answer?

Comment: perhaps later :P I'm very busy now. but if someone else wants to pick up my example and explain what's happening, they're very welcome to do so. --> https://jsfiddle.net/wf1g0n0k/9/